# Get Alphabetical List Of Items in Collection Using Lambda/Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list of objects.  Each object contains a property called 'DisplayName'.

I want to create another list of string objects, where each string represents the first letter or character (could be a number) in the DisplayName property for all objects in the initial list, and I want the list to be distinct.

So, for example, if my list contained the following three objects:

(1) DisplayName = 'Anthony'
(2) DisplayName = 'Dennis'
(3) DisplayName = 'John'

I would want to create another list containing the following three strings:

(1) 'A'
(2) 'D'
(3) 'J'

Any idea how to do this with minimal coding using lambda expressions or linq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
list.Select(o => o.DisplayName[0].ToString())
    .Where(s => Char.IsLetter(s, 0))
    .Distinct().ToList();
```

*Edited*

Comment: Thanks.  Is it possible to filter out results that have a non-alpha character?  I know that my original post stated that it was ok if the first character was numeric or a symbol - but - I am curious if I can filter these out of the results returned?

Comment: Use a Where call with one of the static methods in Char.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<myObject> mylist = new List<myObject>();
//populate list
List<string> myStringList = myList
    .Select(x => x.DisplayName.Substring(0,1))
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(y => y);
```

In the above code, `Select` (with it's lambda) returns only the first character from the display name of object `x`.  This creates an `IEnumerable` of type `string`, which is then passed to `Distinct()`.  This makes sure you have only unique items in the list.  Finally, `OrderBy` makes sure your items are sorted alphabetically.

Note, if each of the objects in the list are of different types, you won't be able to just call `x.DisplayName`.  In that case, I would create an interface, possibly called `IDisplayName`, which implements `DisplayName`.  Then you should be able to use `x => ((IDisplayName)x).DisplayName.Substring(0,1)` within your lambda.

Answer (score 0):

or in query notation:

```
var stringList = (from a in objectList 
                      select a.DisplayName.Substring(0,1)).Distinct();
```

Comment: Query comprehension syntax is overrated.